# AWS Lambda with Provisioned Concurrency still experiencing long startup times

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-sam

Using a SAM template to deploy an apigateway that calls a couple of lambdas.
All lambdas are written in java11 and are connected to a VPC. This adds a lot of delay between calling the function and the code actually starting up (about 30 seconds).

Used

```
      AutoPublishAlias: "latestAlias"
      ProvisionedConcurrencyConfig:
        ProvisionedConcurrentExecutions:
          1
```

to enable Provisioned Concurrency but i still get long starts of 30 seconds from time to time.

Also tried using ping events via `AWS::Events::Rule` to call the lambdas every 9 minutes to keep them warn (i recall reading that 15 minutes of inactivity leads to lambda containers being destroyed). Also left Provisioned Concurrency enabled while doing this, and I still see cold starts. I also see new files being created in CloudWatch logs, indicating that a new container has been spun up.
Using xray to validate that i don't have multiple requests at the same time that might trigger the creating of a new container.

Am I missing something in enabling this? From the documentation i understand that "initialization" should not appear in xray once the lambda has been started. Also, AWS Hyperplane was supposed to reduce lambda-VPC integration times to around 1 second (deploying on eu-central-1 which should have Hyperplane for a while now).

Comment: I'm not sure on the solution, but have you tried to increase provisioned concurrency to test (may be 10, 20 for testing only)? As it seems you have provisioned concurrency as only 1.